# output HTML content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a message on the webpage as result of search . below is my JS code. I kept the DIV empty in the HTML. after calling the function nothing is displaying in the browser.I am novice Please correct where I am doing wrong.

```
   function test() {
    var v = "<p  class=""noresults""> <img src=""icons/oops-icon_small.jpg"" alt=""OOPS!"" >    id=""img_align"" /> we did not find" + "any results relating to your search. </p>" + "<span >    class=""noreult_home""> <a href=""#""><img src=""icons/home_icon.jpg"" alt=""Home""/>       </a> ></span>";

    $("div#con").html(v);
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is hideously invalid. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Quentin, thank you for formatting my question after posting I was trying to correct the format, as you are expert you correct it very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have improve your javscript function

```
function test() {
    var v= "<p class='noresults'><img src='icons/oops-icon_small.jpg' alt='OOPS!' id='img_align'/>we did not find any results relating to your search.</p><span class='noreult_home'><a href='#'><img src='icons/home_icon.jpg' alt='Home'/></a></span>";
    $("div#con").html(v);
}
```

Comment: Tom, thank you for your response, its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function test() { 
  $('<img />').attr('id', 'img_align').append('div#con');
  $('<p></p>').addClass('noresult_home').html('we did not find any results relating to your search.').append('div#con');
}
```